# flask socketio session query string

Tags: python, session, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

this code is supposed to work, but it does not work

As soon as a client connects, the session 'keyo' is assigned to the value 'example'

I tried to make an equivalent of socket.myvariable with session['myvariable']

```
@app.route("/a")
def helljo():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handleMessagae():
    session['keyo'] = request.args.get('session') # /a?session=example
    emit('connected', session.get('keyo'))

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(message):
    emit('message', {'pseudo':session.get('keyo'),'message':message} , broadcast=True, include_self=False)
```

Comment: please explain what does not work, 'it does not work' is not helpful at all

Comment: session.get('keyo') return null and session['keyo'] return None

Comment: I go to /a?session=example. session['keyo'] should be 'example'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do what you want is:

```
@app.route("/a")
def helljo():
    session['keyo'] = request.args.get('session') # /a?session=example
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handleMessagae():
    emit('connected', session.get('keyo'))

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(message):
    emit('message', {'pseudo':session.get('keyo'),'message':message} , broadcast=True, include_self=False)
```

The problem is that you are mixing up the HTTP request with the Socket.IO requests. If you invoke the `/a` endpoint with some query string args, you can only access those arguments in the handler for that endpoint. But saving them in the session makes them accessible later by the Socket.IO event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route("/a", methods=['GET'])
def helljo():
    session['keyo'] = request.args.get('session')
    socketio.emit('EVENT', {'var': session.get('keyo')})
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handleMessagae():
    emit('connected', session.get('keyo'))

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(message):
    emit('message', {'pseudo':session.get('keyo'),'message':message} , broadcast=True, include_self=False)
```

The problem here is, that you're trying to get request arguments within a socketio event, this isn't going to work as request arguments are only accessible inside of an `@app.route()` function.

Comment: That is the question, How comunicate the value 'example' (from the url) to socketio ?

Comment: Try that, you can emit independently of a socketio event. `socketio.emit('EVENT', {'var': session.get('keyo')})`

Comment: How send with socketio.emit only to sender. because it sends to all clients exept sender.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense, please restate your question so I am able to understand it and help you further

Comment: see my post bellow

Answer (score 0):

the fourth line of this code sends to all clients except to sender of the request. I would like to send it only to sender

```
@app.route("/a", methods=['GET'])
def helljo():
    session['keyo'] = request.args.get('session')
    socketio.emit('alert_sender', {'resp': session.get('keyo')})
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handleMessagae():
    emit('connected', 'hi')

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(message):
    emit('message', {'pseudo':session.get('keyo'),'message':message} , broadcast=True, include_self=False)
```

on index.html (when I go on /a?session=example)

```
...
 socket.on('alert_sender', function(data) {
  alert(data.resp);      
 // others receive alert : example    sender receive : nothing
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Alternative Solution :

```
@app.route("/a", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    resp = request.args.get('session')
    return render_template( 'index.html' , resp=resp )

@socketio.on('My_Event')
def message(msg):
    print(msg)
```

on index.html

```
 <script>
      // ...
    {% if resp %}
    variable = '{{ resp }}';
    {% else %}
    variable = 'null';
    {% endif %}

      socket.emit( 'My_Event' , variable );
    // ...
    </script>
```